# Errors building Paraview with gcc on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, gcc, vtk, paraview

I'm trying to build Paraview on OSX 10.10.5 with gcc 5.3.0.

When building Vtk I get:

> [ 24%] Building CXX object
>   VTK/Rendering/OpenGL/CMakeFiles/vtkRenderingOpenGL.dir/vtkCocoaRenderWindowInteractor.mm.o
>   In file included from /usr/include/os/object.h:75:0,
>                    from /usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:48,
>                    from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15,
>                    from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFPropertyList.h:13,
>                    from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:55,
>                    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
>                    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12,
>                    from /Users/Leo/projects/ParaView/VTK/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkCocoaRenderWindowInteractor.mm:16:
>   /usr/include/objc/NSObject.h:22:4: error: 'instancetype' does not name
>   a type
>    - (instancetype)self;
>       ^ /usr/include/objc/NSObject.h:36:4: error: 'instancetype' does not name a type
>    - (instancetype)retain OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE;
>       ^ /usr/include/objc/NSObject.h:38:4: error: 'instancetype' does not name a type
>    - (instancetype)autorelease OBJC_ARC_UNAVAILABLE;
>       ^ /usr/include/objc/NSObject.h:60:4: error: 'instancetype' does not name a type
>    - (instancetype)init;
>       ^ /usr/include/objc/NSObject.h:62:4: error: 'instancetype' does not name a type  + (instancetype)new;
>       ^ /usr/include/objc/NSObject.h:63:4: error: 'instancetype' does not name a type  + (instancetype)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone;
>       ^ /usr/include/objc/NSObject.h:64:4: error: 'instancetype' does not name a type  + (instancetype)alloc;
>       ^ In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:0,
>                    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12,
>                    from /Users/Leo/projects/ParaView/VTK/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkCocoaRenderWindowInteractor.mm:16:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:59:42:
>   error: expected ')' before '(' token
>    - (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
>                                             ^ /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:59:42:
>   error: expected identifier before '(' token
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:59:42:
>   error: expected ';' before '(' token
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:60:81:
>   error: expected ')' before '(' token
>    - (void)enumerateObjectsWithOptions:(NSEnumerationOptions)opts usingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
>   NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);

All errors come from OSX headers `/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NS....h`

I know that GCC doesn't recognize Objective-C Blocks (`^`), and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63651) I found that GCC doesn't understand `instancetype`.

Is there any way to build Paraview on OSX with gcc, should I just deactivate Vtk?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to build anything with GCC that uses the higher level (objective-c) system headers.   You'll either need to use llvm or disable any dependencies on system headers.

Comment: Thanks @bbum, how am I supposed to disable system header dependencies?

Comment: Good question;  if the open source project doesn't support doing so, then you're out of luck.  You'd need to either port it to LLVM or break the dependencies by some other means.  If the code is older, porting will be hard.

Comment: You might try updating the version of VTK.  Looks like they've had recent compatibility work.  http://review.source.kitware.com/#/c/14424/